# Story ID: Wrongfully sentenced by a biased automated judge

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers

I am looking for a short story with the following characteristics:

### Publishing date and possible matches

I don't know when this story was written. I do remember that I read it in a primary school library in Poland, between 2002 and 2007. It may have been a translation, as I originally read it in Polish

This story is definitely not "Computers Don't Argue" by Gordon R. Dickson. The theme was distinctly different, and it was definitely a straightforward story rather than a series of letters. I have searched through the `[story-identification]` tag here and found nothing that looks like a candidate.

### The plot and the setting

#### >90% certain of the following

1. A man gets put on a trial, to be sentenced by an automated judge system. It would be a 1-to-1 hearing with no other humans present.
2. During the hearing, the system only asks a series of loaded/"leading" questions that basically railroad him through to the next, biased and unfair question one by one.
3. He is innocent of the crime he's accused of, but the system refuses to accept any clarifications or objections that he speaks to try to clear himself of the accusation.
4. The man realises that he will be sentenced unjustly if he follows the process, so he attempts to hack the machine in some way to alter the result in his favour. He is unsuccessful.

#### Parts I'm less certain about (90-80% certainty)

- The original event that precipitated the accusation was something the man said in a social setting. IIRC it was critiquing the current government on a minor point or something like that.
- The above might have been interpreted as speech in support of communism and filed for trial under that description.
- The machine's questions were chosen such that the machine could pick the least charitable interpretation and score accordingly.
- The machine's sentencing algorithm revolved around scoring the defendant's answers. Answers that tended towards clearing one's name would receive a positive score, and answers that made it more likely that the defendant is guilty would receive a negative score. A defendant would be sentenced if the score was sufficiently dinged, or cleared if they passed.
- The man was a programmer/one of the programmers of this machine, so knew that there was a way to hack the machine.
- The hack, once completed, would flip the polarity of the negative points awards and turn them into positive point awards. This way, for every "wrong" answer, the machine would award him some positive points and be fooled into increasing his score.
- The machine (or the part the defendant interacted with) was a booth of some kind. The way to hack the system involved opening up a part of the machine's innards from the inside, and rewiring something. There was no mention of hacking in the modern sense, so no keyboard-based hacking with green screens filled with scrolling text.
- The hack was unsuccessful because either the machine itself, or someone on the outside, detected what he was doing.

Comment: Not the answer, but a wrongful sentence by an automated booth judge appears in "The Thirteenth Majestral" (1989) by Hayford Peirce.

Comment: I may have read a Harry Harrison short story with this plot, or something similar, but I am not at all sure.

Comment: Smilar plot line to the story where the man is late to return his library book 'capital punishment' (or some such similar) and the system mix up leads to him being sentenced to death. Error in routing of messages (and one of the judges going on a fishing holiday) means the sentece was carried out... the perils of automation / just following 'the system' the overtones of the message... Computers Don't Argue by Gordon R Dickson.

Comment: @Mike I am aware of that story, but it's definitely not that one :) (see the 2nd para of the question)